# not reflecting changes to the database is there anything wrong with the code?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i've made a gui to enter the data into my database on the click of button but its not reflecting the changes in the database. can anybody resolve the issue?

````
public class ExpenseManager implements ActionListener {
    JFrame frame ;
    JTextField t1 = new JTextField("");
    JTextField t2 = new JTextField("");
    void go(){
        frame = new JFrame("Daily Expenses");
        JButton b = new JButton("SUBMIT");
        frame.add(t1);
        t1.setBounds(50,50,200,30);
        frame.add(t2);
        t2.setBounds(50,100,200,30);
        frame.add(b);
        b.setBounds(50,150,200,30);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/try","root","root");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            String x = t1.getText();
            int x1 = Integer.parseInt(x);
            String y = t2.getText();
            ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("INSERT INTO data (amt, dis) VALUES (x1,y); ");
            con.close();
        }catch(Exception eX){ System.out.println(e);}
    }
}```
````

Comment: Are you sure your actionPerformed method is firing ?

Comment: Do not catch `Exception` like that, let it propagate or print the stack trace alongside message. It will tell you what are you doing wrong.

Comment: Does the sql-`String` really insert the values of `x1` and `y` or does it just try to insert `"x1"` and `"y"`? I would have expected something like `"INSERT INTO data (amt, dis) VALUES (" + x1 + "," + y + ");"`. Using parameters in a query should have been done by using `"?"` in the sql-`String` and a proper `stmt.setParameter(1, x1)` calls...

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` is not a query in java, it is an update. So changing `stmt.executeQuery` to `stmt.executeUpdate` should do the trick. This won't create a ResultSet either, which you don't need in this case.

Also, a quick note, if you program any queries like this, you run into the probability of memory leaks, try using the try-catch-finally statements for database querys, and make sure to always close the connection, result set and statement.
You also only need to do the `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") call once in the beginning of your program.

Comment: hi thank you so much but still not able to insert data into database.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it would be better to follow the best practice by using `PrparedStatment` instead of `Statement`, or at least fix your insert query as you are trying to insert the literal values `x1,y` not the variables `x1` & `y`.
a correct implementation of `PreparedStatement` would be:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO data (amt, dis) VALUES(?,?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, x1);
pstmt.setDouble(2, y);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

if you want to keep using the `Statement` , you should change the type of your query to `executeUpdate` instead of `executeQuery`, and you should append the actual values of your variables as well, a working example could be:

```
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
String x = t1.getText();
int x1 = Integer.parseInt(x);
String y = t2.getText();
String query = String.format("INSERT INTO data (amt, dis) VALUES (%d,%s)",x1,y);
stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

---

**Side Notes:**

- If your application is supposed to make different petitions to the database, you may consider creating an independent method to initialize your connection to the database, so you can call it wherever you feel the need to, a working example could be the following:

```
private Connection connect() {
    // SQLite connection string
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/try";
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "root");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return conn;
}
```

- The `ResultSet` variable in that gets generated after a query that does not fetch data will get you an `Integer` number of the affected rows.

Comment: thank you so much sir but even after using ```String query = String.format("INSERT INTO data (amt, dis) VALUES (%d,%s)",x1,y);``` not reaching to the required solution.